# Trying to show a message on email cancelation if zip code eqauls a value within an array

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am tryinf to show a conditional message if a specific zipcode is added to an order on the checkout page. Code below, but not currently working/

```
{% capture postcodes %}
3000|3122|3051
{% endcapture %}

{% assign postcode_array = postcodes | split: ' |' %}

{% for excludedPostcodes in postcode_array %}
  {% assign postcode_vals = excludedPostcodes | split: '|' %}
  {% if shipping_address.zip == postcode_vals %}
    This is the postcode cancellation message
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the `{% assign postcode_vals = excludedPostcodes | split: '|' %}` line?

The `postcode_array` is already an array, so when you iterate it you should get individual elements in the (unfortunately named) `excludedPostcodes` variable. I don't think there is a need to split it again.

Edit:
Also the line:
`{% assign postcode_array = postcodes | split: ' |' %}` seems to have a typo, there's an extra space before the pipe character.

Something like this should work:

```
{% capture postcodes %}
3000|3122|3051
{% endcapture %}

{% assign postcode_array = postcodes | split: '|' %}

{% for post_code in postcode_array %}
  {% if shipping_address.zip == post_code %}
    This is the postcode cancellation message
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```